# Formally show that the set of continuous functions is not measurable

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $C(\mathbb{R})=\{ f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} \colon \ f \text{ continuous}\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}} $.
How to prove formally that $C(\mathbb{R}) \notin \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})$ (the product sigma algebra)?

The classic proof said that   $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})$ iff exists $J\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $|J|\leq \aleph_0$ and $B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^J})$ such that $A=B \times \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}\setminus J}=\{f \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \colon  \ (f(j) \colon \ t \in J) \in B\}$. In simpler terms,  $A$ only can have countable restrictions but the set of continuous functions have uncountable restrictions since every function on $C(\mathbb{R})$ needs to be continuous in every point $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

The last part of this proof always didn't satisfied me at all, and I don't really know how to do this proof formally.

Any help or references will be appreciated.

Comment: You do believe/see that the statement about Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is true?

Comment: Just notice that any continuous function on ${\bf R}$ can be modified on any cocountable set (indeed, on any nonempty set) so that the result is discontinuous.

Comment: A more direct approach: given nonempty A, construct explicitly a discontinuous function that is in A. Or, if you like, construct two functions in A which can't both be continuous. Hint: You have total freedom to modify the function off J.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let consider a mapping $T:C(R)\to R^{Q}$ defined by $T(f)=(f(q))_{q \in Q}$, where $Q$ denotes a set of all rational numbers of $R$. It is obvious that $T$ is injective which implies that $card(C(R))\le card(R^Q)=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=
2^{\aleph_0\times \aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$, where $\aleph_0$ denotes the cardinality of all natural numbers.

If we assume that $C(R)$ is measurable with respect to product topology then there  will be a countable parameter set $J \subset R$ and a non-empty Borel subset $A \subseteq R^J$ such that
$C(R)=A \times R^{R \setminus J}$. Notice that $$card(A \times R^{R \setminus J})\ge 1 \times card(R^{R \setminus J})=card(R^R)={2^{\aleph_0}}^{2^{\aleph_0}}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}>2^{\aleph_0}$$ and we get the contradiction.

Comment: We have the following interesting property:  For each measurable (w.r.t. product topology) subset $A$ of $R^R$ we have : $Card(A)=0$ or $card(A)=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$; As consequence we get that each subset $B \subset R^R$ with $0<card(B)<2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$is not measurable w.r.t.product topology. For example, a set $C \subset R^R$ with $card(C)=2^{\aleph_0}$ is not measurable w.r.t.product topology.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a direct argument following tomasz's suggestion.  Let's take as given your characterization of the measurable sets $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R})$.

Let $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R})$ be arbitrary.  We will show $A \ne C(\mathbb{R})$.  If $A = \emptyset$ we are done.  Otherwise, suppose $f \in A$.  If $f$ is not continuous, we are done.  Otherwise, suppose $f$ is continuous.  We know $A$ is of the form $A = B \times \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R} \setminus J}$, where $B \subset \mathbb{R}^J$ and $J$ is at most countable.  Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, $\mathbb{R} \setminus J$ is nonempty, so let $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus J$.  Define $g$ by $g(y) = f(y)+1$ and $g(x) = f(x)$ for $x \ne y$.  Then $g \in A$, but $g$ is certainly not continuous.

Comment: What’s the difference between $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})$ and does $C(\mathbb{R})\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{R}} $?

Comment: @RandomHarry: I don't know what you mean by $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{R}}$.  How are you defining this notation, or where did you see it?  The literal meaning would seem to be the collection of arbitrary products of Borel sets, but that isn't a very useful collection (for instance, $\{(0,0), (1,1)\}$ is not a product of Borel sets) and in particular is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I read it in a script, where it’s also not defined properly. But I would say it means at every point on $\mathbb{R}$, function is allowed to take value in Borel set $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Roughly speaking, I think it’s an analogy of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Can you make that more precise?

Comment: $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{R}}$ is the sigma algebra making the coordinate mapping measurable, while $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})$ is the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ equipped with the product topology. Sorry for being not precise earlier.

Comment: Oh, I see.  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R})$ in this question is *not* denoting the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, but rather the product $\sigma$-algebra, which is the same as what you are denoting by $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^\mathbb{R}$.  The two are clearly different; for example singletons are not measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra.  That does leave the question of whether $C(\mathbb{R})$ is a Borel set in the product topology of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$; I don't know the answer to that offhand.

Comment: @RandomHarry: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4307532/is-the-set-of-continuous-functions-analytic alleges that the answer is no, but doesn't give a proof or reference.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you elaborate what does singleton mean here? Is it something like a point in the space of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{ R}}$? Regarding the second question, I think it’s because $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{R}}\subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})$? Under the definition I provided in the comment above.

Comment: "Singleton" means a set with exactly one element.  Here, a set consisting of exactly one point in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, i.e. exactly one function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  (The proof that such sets are not in the product $\sigma$-algebra is very similar to the argument given in this answer.)  It's true that the product $\sigma$-algebra is a proper subset of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra; we know $C(\mathbb{R})$ is not in the former, but that doesn't resolve whether it is in the latter.