# Why is the set of continous paths of a browian motion not measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, borel-sets

Øksendal states in his book "stochastic differential equations" (*Defintion 2.2.1 iii), p.13*) that

> the set $H = \{\ \omega \mid t → B_t (\omega)\ \text{is continuous}\
> \}$ is not measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra
>   $\mathcal{B}$ on $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{[0,\infty)}$ (...) ($H$ involves an uncountable number of $t$'s),

where $B_t$ is a brownian motion and we identify $\omega$ with the path of $B_t(\omega)$.

Unfortunately I don't know much about $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^n)^{[0,\infty)})$ aside its defintion. According to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/860877/400070) a set $A$ is measurable iff there exists $J\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $|J|≤\aleph_0$ and $B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^J)$ such that $A=B \times \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}\setminus J}=\{f \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \colon  \ (f(j) \colon \ t \in J) \in B\}$.

I would appreciate it, if someone could provide me a reference for the statement above.

**Edit:** If I am not mistaken the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^n))^{[0,\infty)}$ is a true subset of the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^n)^{[0,\infty)})$ and thus the statement above should be correct for the product, but not for the Borel algebra. Prior to the quote Øksendal writes (*after Definition 2.1.4, p. 10*):

> $\mathcal{B}$ [the algebra generated by cylindrical sets] is the same as the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\tilde{\Omega}$ [$=(\mathbb{R}^n)^T$] ­ if $T = [0,\infty)$ and $\tilde{\Omega}$ ­ is given
>   the product topology

This should be false or am I missing something?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/508767/36150

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The linked question is asking about the "cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra" (which should be $\otimes_{t \in [0,1]}\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?). Isn't the Borel $\sigma$-algbra $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^n)^{[0,\infty)})$ bigger than said product? Therefore I still don't understand why $H$ (or $C([0,1])$) could not be measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^n)^{[0,\infty)})$.

Comment: What is your definition of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{[0,\infty)}$? Typically, the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on this space is defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which makes all projections $\pi_t$ measurable, and hence it equals the cyclindrical $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Isn't the Borel $\sigma$-algebra usually generated by the open sets. So if $\tau$ is the product topology on $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{[0,\infty)}$, I would define $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^n)^{[0,\infty)})$ as $\sigma(\tau)$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't see it. So the product topology is the coarsest topology such that all projections are continuous. Let's consider $\pi_i^{-1}({0})=\mathbb{R}^{[0,i)}\times \{0\}\times \mathbb{R}^{(i,\infty)}$ for all $i \in [0,\infty)$ ($n=1$ for simplicity). This would be a closed set and the intersection $\{0\}\times\dots\times\{0\}$ would still be closed in $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ and therefore in $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R})^{[0,\infty)})$. Couldn't elements of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylindrical sets only depend on countable many restrictions?

Comment: Ah, right, I did a stupid mistake there; sorry.

Comment: @saz where's the mistake?

Comment: @Richard This question is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2944642/36150

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately there aren't any useful answers at the moment. I will check back in a few days :)

Answer (score 2):

(I'm going to assume that $\Omega=\Bbb R^{[0,\infty)}$.) As Øksendal notes, if $H$ were measurable then there would be a countable set $(t_n)\subset[0,\infty)$ and a Borel set $B\in\mathcal B({\Bbb R}^{\Bbb N})$ such that $H=\{\omega\in\Omega: (\omega(t_1),\omega(t_2),\ldots)\in B\}$. In particular, this would mean that if $\omega$ and $\omega^*$ were two elements of $\Omega$ with $\omega(t_n)=\omega^*(t_n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, and if $\omega\in H$, then so too $\omega^*\in H$. But clearly if we take any element $\omega\in H$ (that is, a continuous path) and  define $\omega^*(t):=\omega(t)$ for all $t$ except one point $t^*\in [0,\infty)\setminus\{t_1,t_2,\ldots\}$ and set $\omega^*(t^*)=\omega(t^*)+17$, then $\omega^*$ passes the test (involving $(t_n)$ and $B$) for inclusion in $H$ but $\omega^*$ is not continuous.

Comment: Could you provide me the page number on which Øksendal writes that? Thank you :)  Also I'm not entirely sure whether this is correct or not. If I am not mistaken $I := \{\{0\}\times\dots\times\{0\}\}$ should be in $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R})^{[0,\infty)})$, but I can't display said set $I$ as $I=\{\omega\in\Omega: (\omega(t_1),\omega(t_2),\ldots)\in B\}$, since $(t_n)\subset[0,\infty)$ is supposed to be countable.

Comment: Sorry, I misquoted.  What I wrote is a rephrasing of of your own statement just before the reference "According to this question". In any event, your example $I$ is not a subset of $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)^{[0,\infty)}$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However the "According to this question"-statement seems wrong. I am still unsure whether it is in $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^n)^{[0,\infty)})$ (not the product) or not.

Comment: John, why do you say « if H were measurable then there would be a countable set $(t_n)\subset [0,\infty)$ and a Borel set B» ?

Comment: (I take $n=1$) A set $H\subset\Omega:=\Bbb R^{[0,\infty)}$ is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F:=\mathcal B(\Bbb R)^{[0,\infty)}$ if and only if it has the form $\{\omega: (\omega(t_1),\omega(t_2),\ldots)\in A\}$.  This is an old result, due to Doob. Here's a sketch. Let $\mathcal G$ be the collection of subsets of $\Omega$ of the prescribed form.  Clearly $\mathcal G\subset\mathcal F$. Also, $\mathcal G$ is a $\sigma$-field containing all the generators of $\mathcal F$. From this  it follows that $\mathcal F\subset\mathcal G$.