# What is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)}$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

What is the Borel $\sigma -$algebra of $\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)}$ ? I guess that $$\mathscr B(\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)})=\sigma \left\{\prod_{t\in [0,t)}O_t\mid \forall t\geq 0, O_t\text{ open }\text{ and } O_t\neq \mathbb R\text{ for a finite number of }t\right\}.$$

1) Is it correct ?

After, I think that  $$\mathscr B(\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)})=\mathscr B(\mathbb R)^{[0,\infty)}$$ and that

$$\mathscr B(\mathbb R)^{[0,\infty)}=\sigma \left\{\prod_{t\in [0,t)}B_t\mid \forall t\geq 0, B_t\in \mathscr B(\mathbb R)\text{ and } B_t\neq \mathbb R\text{ for a finite number of }t\right\}.$$

2) Is this correct or not really ? I know if $\mathbb R^J$ and $J$ finite, then $\mathscr B(\mathbb R^J)=\mathscr B(\mathbb R)^J$, but is it also true if $J$ is infinite ?

Answer (score 1):

1): NO! Your equality does not make sense. On the left you have a family of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$, and on the left you have the set of functions from $[0,\infty)$ to the Borel algebra of $\mathbb{R}$.

The Borel algebra of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ is not the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that make all projections measurable; it is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all the open sets. In the case of uncountably many factors these two are different. The latter is much larger than the former. Every point in the product is closed and hence Borel but for each element, $B$, of the first algebra there is a countable subset $C$ of $[0,\infty)$ and a Borel subset $B'$ of the product $\mathbb{R}^C$ such that $B=B'\times\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)\setminus C}$.

Comment: Thank you. And for 2) ?

Comment: All thos products you mention are in the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes the projections measurable; the last sentence of my answer describes that algebra in full

Comment: So if I understand well $$\mathscr B(\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)})=\sigma \left\{\prod_{t\geq 0}O_t\mid \forall t,O_t\text{ open and }O_t\neq \mathbb R\text{ for a finite number of $t$}\right\} \ \ ?$$
And $$\mathscr B(\mathbb R)^{[0,\infty)}=\sigma \left\{\prod_{t\geq 0}O_t\mid \forall t, O_t\in \mathscr B(\mathbb R), \text{$O_t\neq \mathbb R$ for a finite number of $t$}\right\}$$ but both are not egal.

Comment: The first equality is false, as indicated in my answer: every one-point set is in the left-hand side but not in the right-hand side.
As to the second equality: I my answer interpret the left-hand side as a set of functions (see my `NO!'), apparently you mean something else.

Comment: $\mathscr B(\mathbb R)^{[0,\infty)}$ is not a set of function, is the product $\sigma -$algebra. But I had confirmation that 2) is correct. For 1) I still don't understand. What do you mean by "one-point set" ? For you $\{1\}$ is in $\mathscr B(\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)})$ ? How can it be ? Since $\{1\}$ is even not an element of $\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)}$ ?

Comment: One-point set: set with one point in it. Every function $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ and hence determines a one-point set.