# Is the set of continuous functions analytic?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Consider the space $X=[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$. Seeing this space as the product of probability spaces ($[0,1]$ equipped with lebesgue measure), we get a structure of probability space on it, with $\sigma-$algebra $\Sigma$ generated by cylinders $A=\prod A_k$ where each $A_k$ is a Borel set and $A_k\neq [0,1]$ for only a finite number of $k$.
$\Sigma$ is easily seen to be also the Borel $\sigma-$ algebra on $X$ equipped with the product topology (since the space is separable)

Now, the set of continuous functions $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ is not in $\Sigma$, that is it is not a Borel subset of $X$ (equipped with the product topology).
My question is: Is it an analytic set?

By analytic set I mean the continuous image of a $K_{\sigma \delta}$ subset of a topological space, where $K$ denotes compact sets.

Comment: Since $X$ is not Polish you should specify which definition of analytic you are using

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Noted, will edit